# How do I remove "Shop By" in the left-hand-column?

Tags: css, magento

When viewing a list of products in categories I have a "Shop By" filter in the left-hand-column of my store front end.  This allows users to view products in specified price ranges.

Try as I might I can't find a way to disable / remove it from view.  I've read various code hacks for previous versions of Magento which claim to work (they didn't for me) - but (a) I don't like the idea of hacking core code and (b) all the tips I've seen pre-date v1.8.1.

Is there something I can use in CSS to cleanly disable the "Shop By" feature? (thinking along the lines of a display:none) Failing that any code modification (as minimal as possible....) would be gratefully received.

Real shame there doesn't seem to be an option in admin to switch this off.  Unless I've missed it?....

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have a link to the site?

Comment: Can you post some relevant HTML please

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `catalog.xml` of your theme (if your theme does not have that file, just copy it from `base/default`) and remove any trace of this text

```
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
```

Comment: Even better, you can probably remove it via your `local.xml`with something like `<remove name="" />` or `<action method="unsetChild">`  http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/  But xml is the cleanest way to go, because then Magento won't build that html.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found in Magento 2 was to modify `/magento/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme_name>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` to remove the block.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Clear your cache with `php bin/magento cache:flush`, and you those "Shop By" options should now be gone.